# Extract Username From Log Text using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to extract all usernames that has failed login atempts from Event Viewer log and then list only the usernames. However the data for each entry is text so I have a hard time extracting only the names (Intruder123 in this case). It would be a couple of hundred account names stored in an array.

```
$String = Get-WinEvent @{LogName='Security';ProviderName='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing';ID=4625 }  -ComputerName SECRETSERVER |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Message

$string -match "Account Name:       (?<content>.*)"
$matches['content']
```

The data looks like this (multiple times):

```
Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        S-1-0-0
    Account Name:       Intruder123
    Account Domain:     SECRET.LOCAL
```

Comment: How much events are you trying to look through?  `$Events = Get-WinEvent @{LogName='Security';ProviderName='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing';ID=4625;MaxEvents='50' };
$Events | Select-String -InputObject {$_.message} -Pattern 'my pattern'`.

Comment: You should ask a specific question. Is there something not working as expected? Do you get error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could collect some more information like the time the failed logon happened and on which computer. For that, create a resulting array of objects.
Also, trying to parse the Message property can be cumbersome and I think it is much better to get the info from the Event as XML:

```
$filter = @{LogName='Security';ProviderName='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing';ID=4625 }
$result = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $filter -ComputerName SECRETSERVER | ForEach-Object {
    # convert the event to XML and grab the Event node
    $eventXml = ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event
    $userName = ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'TargetUserName' }).'#text'
    $computer = ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'WorkstationName' }).'#text'
    # output the properties you need
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Time     = [DateTime]$eventXml.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime
        UserName = $userName
        Computer = $computer
    }
}

# output on screen
$result

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\FailedLogons.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Fantastic! Works exactly how I wanted it.
Can you clarify why it is converted to XML?

Comment: @Salve Each event object returned from `Get-WinEvent` has a `.ToXml()` method. This is also used when you look at the tab XML in the Windows eventviewer. Having the data as XML makes parsing a lot easier than trying to regex your way through the Message property of the event (which is **localized** text).